# how to receive json array in golang with echo

Tags: vuejs2

in vue I have the following structure let dat = [
{
name: "johan",
"Age": "21"
},
{
name: "camilo",
Age: "22"
}
]

I would like to know how to receive this data in go with echo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Bind` function on the handlers `echo.Context` to unmarshal the data into a matching structure.

Example below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func main() {
    // setup echo
    e := echo.New()
    e.POST("/people", PeopleHandler())

    // start webserver
    http.Handle("/", e)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

// PeopleHandler endpoint handler
func PeopleHandler() echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        p := &[]Person{}
        if err := c.Bind(p); err != nil { // here unmarshal request body into p
            return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        }

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, p)
    }
}

// Person represents an individual.
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  string `json:"age"`
}
```

Test via curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '[{"name":"johan","Age":"21"},{"name": "camilo","Age": "22"}]' \
  http://localhost:8080/people
```